# i coded a spambot, but its really fast, and i need it to be a bit slower

Tags: python

this is the code, and when i start it, its really fast, is there any way to make the loop a little slower? first it didnt show the counting, but then i fixed it by adding the count function. first it wasnt counting down, but i fixed that by adding the count function.

```
    import pyautogui
    import time

    msg = input("Enter the message: ")
    n = input("How many times ?: ")

    print("spamming in")

    count = 5
    while(count != 0):
    print(count)
    time.sleep(1)
    count -= 1


for i in range(0,int(n)):
    pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
```

Comment: Do the same in your for loop as you done in your while loop, ad a sleep statement to sleep for a bit of time before writing the next message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it slower the same way you made the while loop slower, add a `time.sleep` call:

```py
for i in range(0,int(n)):
    pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)  # the greater the number is, the more delay.
```

Comment: how would i make the spambot go to another window, run the loop, and make it so i can go to a diffrent window and make the loop run only on the first window

Comment: @HnightR I don't know, if you can't find a sulotion online, you should ask this as a different SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `time.sleep(x)` variable x to something like 3 or 5 or how long you want your pause between messages to be.

Comment: how would i make the spambot go to another window, run the loop, and make it so i can go to a diffrent window and make the loop run only on the first window?

Comment: Make a new question for it and keep in mind that stackoverflow community will not code for you, we can help resolve an issue or solve a problem.